# How to confirm navigation for a link in a href tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using simple links for an admin panel but in case of user accidently clicks on link for user deletion, there should be a confirmation pop-up for avoding this.

Probably as you know a href tag's are not fully compatible with javascript. So, i have used span tag for "onclick" but that didn't went so well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_click()
{
return confirm("Are you sure ?");
}

</script>
```

Here is the html code for link:

```
   <span onclick="confirm_click();">    <a title="Delete User" href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-remove-sign">DELETE</i></a></span>
```

Comment: What factor is preventing you from using an anchor on its own?

Comment: You also don't need to test a bool against `true`, you can simply have `function confirm_click(){return confirm("Are you sure ?");}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try...

```
<a title="Delete User" onclick="return confirm_click();" href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-remove-sign">DELETE</i></a>
```

...instead.

You need to *return* the value of your method, and returning false in an onclick event prevents the default behaviour (which in this case would be to navigate to the href).

Comment: Well, if it solves your problem flag it as an answer...

Comment: @Guarita I have to wait for 15 minutes first i suppose. That's why couldn't accept it quickly

Comment: Oops, my bad... I wasn't aware of that rule in the community. Thought you had forgotten to check it correct. :)

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
<a href='/path/to/action' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?')">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code:

```
<a title="Delete User" id="delete" href="http://www.google.com"><i class="icon-remove-sign">DELETE</i></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('delete').onclick = function(e){
    if( !confirm('Are you sure?') ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
</script>
```

and I think we avoid using 'onclick' and so on in HTML in order to make HTML and JavaScript separate

Answer (score 0):

This javascript will do the job

```
function confirmDelete(delUrl) 
    {
        if (confirm("Sample message")) 
        {
            document.location = delUrl;
        }
    }
```

Obviously you have to assing it to

```
<a href="javascript:confirmDelete('yourPath')">Delete</a>
```

Comment: I agree, I don't like your solution much either (sorry!), but being downvoted and not knowing why is not helpful.

Comment: Hey, it wasn't me who downvoted you, I was agreeing that I think you need to know why you were downvoted!

Comment: @MadSkunk yeah, I know. I was only try to explain that to "others" who reads :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onunload="return confirm_click()">
```

When the page is going to be unloaded your confirm message is prompted

A resource about unload event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp

Comment: Not a good answer, what if the page is unloaded for another reason?

Comment: It is a general and global solution.